# Adding 'only' before prefetch related slows down query

Tags: django, django-orm

In pseudocode, I have a db model like this:

```
Model T
    name
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name="Ts")
    symbol = models.ForeignKey(Symbol)

Model Symbol
    name
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

Model Tag
    name
```

And this is the code I use to export it:

```
query = T.objects.annotate(category_id=F('symbol__category_id')).prefetch_related('tags')

for t in query:
    _dict = model_to_dict(t)
    _dict["category_id"] = t.category_id

    _tags = []
    for tag in _dict["tags"]
        _tags.append(tag.id)
    _dict["tags"] = _tags
```

In this code, `_dict` gives me the wanted result.

However, T has many other fields I don't need, so I changed `query` to:

```
T.objects.only("name", "symbol", "tags").annotate(category=F('symbol__category_id')).prefetch_related('tags')
```

For some reason, this slows down the execution.

Original query takes 6 seconds while the last one takes 8 seconds. Why?

How can I prefetch everything correctly so that I don't have to loop over tags and append their ids in a dictionary? How can I do this while also using `.only()`?

EDIT:

for some reason, using `.defer()` instead of only, and indicating the fields I don't want, works without any performance hit.

What's the difference between `defer` and `only`, and why one creates a performance bottleneck?

Comment: What if you add a `'pk'` to your `only`?

Comment: Still slower than without it

Comment: Note that you do not need to include `'symbol'` here. The `only` only has impact on the "select" part, not on the filtering, and other related objects.

Comment: Yeah, I also tried with and without symbol, to see if the prefetching of category was the problem.

Comment: But here you do not really fetch the `category` itself, you only fetch the primary key, so you did not solve the N+1 problem.

Comment: The category id is the only thing I need in my _dict, sorry that wasn't clear.

Comment: but then it should be `_dict["category"] = t.category_id`, and better not `t.category`.

Comment: You mean that for code clarity or does it change in terms of functionality? Becase by inspecting with the debugger I can see that t.category is an integer with the category id (and not the category model). annotate with symbol__category is probably the same SQL as annotate with symbol__category_id

Comment: edited my question with category.id to make it more clear, although it does the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `fields = ("name", ...)`

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch
prefetch = Prefetch('tags', queryset=Tag.objects.only('id'))
query = T.objects.prefetch_related(prefetch).annotate(category_id=F('symbol__category_id')).only(*fields)

for t in query:
    _dict = model_to_dict(t, fields=[*fields, tags])
    _dict["category_id"] = t.category_id
    _dict["tags"] = [tag.id for tag in _dict["tags"]]
```